# Search for a line in a file and display results on separate lines with text

Tags: python, string, search, field, line

I have a txt file that I wish to search for an 'id'. Each line in the file contains 5 fields (id, name, age, height, weight). If the id search finds a match, I want to display each field in the matched line as below:

```
    x 'player/s have been found:'
    print('Player ID: ', id)
    print('Player name: ', name)
    print('Age: ', age)
    print('Height: ', height)
    print('Weight: ', weight)
```

So far I have only been able to print the matched line as a line and not pull individual fields out onto different print lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have so far, but python cant seem to readline any matches..

def search_enter_id():
    '''Function allows user to search for a player ID from Players.txt file'''

```
# Create a bool variable to use as a flag
found = False

# Get search value
my_string = input('Please enter the player ID you want to search: ')

# Open a file for reading
player_file = open('Players.txt', 'r')

# Read the first records ID field
id_field = player_file.readline()

# Read the rest of the file
while id_field != '':
    # Read the name field
    name_field = player_file.readline()

    # Read Age field
    age_field = player_file.readline()

    #Read Height field
    height_field = player_file.readline()

    #Read weight field
    weight_field = player_file.readline()

    # Strip the \t\t from fields
    id_field = id_field.rstrip('\t\t')
    name_field = name_field.rstrip('\t\t')
    age_field = age_field.rstrip('\t')
    height_field = height_field.rstrip('\t\t')
    weight_field = weight_field.rstrip('\n')

    # Determine whether this record matches the search value
    if id_field == my_string:
        # Display the record
        print('Player ID: ', id_field)
        print('Player name: ', name_field)
        print('Age: ', age_field)
        print('Height: ', height_field)
        print('Weight: ', weight_field)
        print()
        # Set the found flag to true
        found = True

    # Read the next ID field
    id_field = player_file.readline()

# Close the file
player_file.close()

# If the search value was not found in the file
# display a message
if not found:
    print('That ID was not found in the file.')
```

Answer (score 0):

After you match a line, split it.
array = line.split('xxx')
* replace the xxx with your delimiter
now you can use your array to get the individual fields out.

Comment: delimiter is the chars that you split by (usually comma/space/! or what ever, I wrote xxx just so it will be easy to add the replace comment :) )